# How to add time to countdown timer?

Tags: android, timer, onclicklistener, countdowntimer

I know there is a post like this but it does not answer the question clearly.
I have a little game where you tap a head and it moves to a random position and you get +1 to score. Meanwhile there is a timer counting down from 60000 (60 seconds) and displaying below.
How can I make it so whenever the head is tapped, it adds a second to the timer?

```
new CountDownTimer(timer, 1) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textTimer.setText("Timer " + millisUntilFinished/1000);
    }
    public void onFinish() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gameover.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}.start();
```

and in the onClickListner event I have:

```
timer=timer+1000;
```

It currently doesn't work as in there is no time added on the click.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: the only way is to call cancell on the current instance and create a new instance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't change the time of a scheduled timer. The only way to achieve what you are trying to do is by cancelling the timer and setting up a new one.

```
public class CountdownActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{
    CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    long countdownPeriod;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_countdown);
       countdownPeriod = 30000;
       createCountDownTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (mCountDownTimer != null)
                mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        createCountDownTimer();

        return true;
    }

    private void createCountDownTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(countdownPeriod + 1000, 1) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    textTimer.setText("Timer " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                countdownPeriod=millisUntilFinished;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Gameover.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: mr. G_J i have a question?  mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(countdownPeriod + 1000, 1)  in this line we are initializing the timer with +1 sec? so it means when we create the timer in OnCreate method the actual time is not 30 sec? it will be 31? thanks ..

Comment: need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585264/how-to-set-time-of-timepicker-to-countdowntimer