# Adding five seconds to countdown timer with button click

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

Hi I'm implementing a quiz game with a timer on each question.
The Countdown timer is currently ten seconds long, starts in the onCreate method and counts down as expected.

However I am trying to implement when the user clicks on a button the timer updates with an extra five seconds. Anything I try doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure if I will need to create a new timer and just update the text view.

My current code can be seen below. Help is very much appreciated.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


...........

  }       

} catch (InterruptedException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
       startTimer(10000); 
    }

private void startTimer(long remaningMillis){

    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000){

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             time.setText("Timer: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             time.setText("Timer: 0");
             alert("Oh, no! You are out of Time! You Lost a Life");
             --mLives;
             lives.setText(String.valueOf(mLives));
             saveData();
         }
      }.start();
}



public void onTimeBoostButtonClicked(View arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Time Boost button clicked.");
    if (mTimeBoosts == 0) alert("Oh, no! You are out of Time Boosts! Try buying some!");
    else {
         --mTimeBoosts;
        TextView NumTimeBooststextView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.NumTimeBooststextView);
        NumTimeBooststextView.setText(String.valueOf(mTimeBoosts));
        saveData();

       //TODO Add 5 seconds to timer



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383584/how-to-add-time-to-countdown-timer) you cannot change the countdown of a scheduled timer you can cancel it and start a new one. Please check the accepted answer in the link.

Comment: How did I not see this? I will accept this as the answer thanks anyway.