# Start timer on button click

Tags: android, timer, handler

I'm new in Android programming but i know Java.
My question is, how does a timer work in Android? I've read that is better to use a handler.
What I want to do is, you click a button and the timer starts. To the moment when the button is clicked all is clear for me but how to start the timer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read this so your things don't get downvoted to oblivion: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How does a timer work in Android?

You better read [Timer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), [CountDownTimer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) and [Handler Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

> To the moment, when the button is clicked, all is cleared for me; but, how can I start the timer?

If I didn't misunderstand your question, when you say `Timer`, you refer to `CounteDownTimer`. So, you should have something like this:

(I've written a sample code. So, you should understand it first, and then, you should apply it to your code.)

**Adding the `Buttons`**

```
btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt1);
btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bt2);
```

**Adding the `SetOnClickListener()`**

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

    });
}

btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

    });
}
```

My `btn1` starts the `CountDownTimer`, and the second one stops and clears it.

Now, I create an [Inner Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) with `CountDownTimerTest` name.

```
public class CountDownTimerTest extends CountDownTimer {
    public CountDownTimerTest(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        text.setText("Time's up!");
        timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(startTime));
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        text.setText("Time remain:" + millisUntilFinished);
        timeElapsed = startTime - millisUntilFinished;
        timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(timeElapsed));
    }
}
```

Then on my `btn1`, I put this code (start the `CountDownTimer`):

```
countDownTimer.start();
```

And on my `btn2`, I put this code (stop/cancel the `CountDownTimer`):

```
countDownTimer.cancel();
```

Now, I hope that you can understand how `CountDownTimer` works, if your question isn't about `CountDownTimer`, let me know, and I'll update my answer as soon as possible with your wishes.

### EDIT - Only with one `Button`

To do it with the same `Button`, you can do this:

Create a `Boolean` variable as:

```
Boolean ButtonClicked = false;
```

And then, modify the code as follows:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (!ButtonClicked)) {
            ButtonClicked = true;
            countDownTimer.start(); 
        } else {
            ButtonClicked = false;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }                       
    });
}
```

### EDIT 2 Get what button is clicked

You can create an `int` called `NumberButtonClicked` like this :

```
int NumberButtonClicked = 0;
```

Then on every `Button` you have you'll have to do this (Example) :

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            NumberButtonClicked = 1;
    });
}
```

Then you know that if you have clicked `btn1` your variable will be 1.

Comment: Ok thank you, but how does it works with one button, so you press the button and the timer runs till hes over?

Comment: Be careful when using Timer, because it's not stop when you leave your activity. It may cause NPE if you update views in that case.

Comment: Good comprehensive answer. Downvoting someone's very first question on SO without providing guidance or answer is just mean.

Comment: Thank you for youre time and this great answer.

Comment: If it helped you **must** mark it as a correct answer :)

Comment: I only have a last question, is there a way to get a boolean value from onclick? or do i need a global var?

Comment: What do you mean @Phil? I don't understand what are you asking to me

Comment: Ok the background is i need 4 buttons and when the buttons are clicked, time will be added to the counter, but i want to know which button is clicked, so i hoped that there is some return value from the onClick() Method from a Button?

Comment: @Phil What do you want to return?

Comment: Something what fits like if(button.onClick() == true)

Comment: @Phil See the edit, if you don't understand you can join on this [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54844/persian-chat) and I'll help you

Comment: Ok Thank you, thats a good idea, its late i sleep now, i got problems with     private Button right = (Button)findViewById(R.id.right);

    right.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {/* Some Code */ });    it says ->invalid method declaration; return type requiered. I'm to tired to take a closer look, so thank you for all

Comment: Nicely explained. +1 ;)

Comment: Got another problem, need to add time to the countdowntimer but i read that is not possible, i need to cancel one and start a new. But why? the countdowntimer class must have a parameter which show the remaining seconds or?

Comment: You can see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383584/how-to-add-time-to-countdown-timer) or search on StackOverflow... I think your quesiton is answered correctly that's why you have to mark it as a correct and if you have more doubts you have to create another question and if you want you give me the question url :)