# How to increase time in count down timer?

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer

```
public void counter(){
        new CountDownTimer(20000, 1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000)));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                gameOver();

            }
        }.start();
    }
```

I am trying to write a game in which player gets 20 seconds to play. A timer starts at start of the game and if timer reaches 0, player looses. If player presses  button with correct answer, i want time to increase by 3 seconds. But I don't know how to add time in the count down timer whenever player hits correct answer. I tried everything but couldn't find a way. If there is another method to achieve this, please tell me. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add time to countdown timer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383584/how-to-add-time-to-countdown-timer)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
private int globalCount = 0; // Initialize this in Global scope of class.

public void counter(int timeCount){

globalCount = 0; 

    new CountDownTimer(timeCount, 1000){
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000)));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
         if (globalCount == 0) {
            gameOver();
          } else {
           conter(globalCount);
            }

        }
    }.start();
}
```

One last thing you have to do is:

```
globalCount += 3000;
```

every time when user pressed the right answer button. Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks Zohaib, I have doubt. How will globalCount update value of millisUntilFinished?? Because Progress Bar is also working with millisUntilFinished.

Comment: Your "globalCount" will be updated from the method where user will hit the right answer. It will be getting the value from there. And "millisUntilFinished" is automatically calculated value from "timeCount" and "1000" on every iteration. Don't worry about that, try it. It'll work!

Answer (score 0):

In Android normal countdown timer is used for decrease order. so you can use logic using normal if-else condition.

```
            if (sec==59){
                sec = 0;
                min = min+1;
                String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d min: %02d sec",min,sec);
                editText.setText(text);

            }else {
                sec = sec+1;
                String text = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d min: %02d sec",min,sec);
                editText.setText(text);

            }

        }
```

You can get complete code using [this blog](https://theandroidcodings.blogspot.com/2019/04/increase-time-using-countdowntimer.html)