# How Do I Let A Button Create A Countdown Timer, And Then Whenever It Is Clicked Again Add Time To The Timer?

Tags: java, timer, countdowntimer

I've got this button and when it is clicked it creates a timer.

The Problem is, it creates a timer every click.

What I wanted this button to do was to on the initial click, create a timer, and then on all subsequent clicks add five seconds to the **myTime** variable, until the timer ran out.

How would I remedy this?

This is the code that is executed when then button is clicked:

```
    myTime = myTime + 5000
    new CountDownTimer(myTime, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            myButton.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            myButton.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: Here you go friend: [check this thread out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383584/how-to-add-time-to-countdown-timer)

Comment: Removed confusing lines with just /.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to delete the timer and restart it.  Capture the milliseconds of the last tick and add your 5 seconds to that. Make the ticks smaller so you don't lose a lot of time.

```
CountDownTimer myTimer = null;
long myTime = STARTING_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
...
// In the button click action performed event

if (myTimer != null) {
    myTimer.cancel();  // Cancel the existing timer
    myTime = myTime + 5000;  // Add five seconds to the remaining time.
}
// Start a new timer with the remaining time as the starting point.
myTimer = new CountDownTimer(myTime, 100) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            myButton.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            // Save the remaining time
            myTime = millisUntilFinished;
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            myButton.setText("done!");
        }
}.start();
```

Comment: Sorry, but where is it I put "CountDownTimer myTimer = null;"? I'm not quite sure. Should it be in the create function or just in the class?